# GridView not showing because of file download

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, datatable

I am setting up a gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="Grd_PayCodes" AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Data Found!" OnPageIndexChanged="Grd_PayCodes_PageIndexChanged" runat="server">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100" datafield="Item1" headertext="PayCode" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100" DataField="Item2" HeaderText="Hours" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="100" DataField="Item3" HeaderText="Dollars" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

With Data from:

```
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Item1"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Item2"))
    dt.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("Item3"))
    dt.Rows.Add("Data1","Data2","Data3")
    dt.AcceptChanges()
    Grd_PayCodes.DataSource = dt
    Grd_PayCodes.DataBind()
```

And following it up by downloading a file:

```
   Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
   tw = New StreamWriter(ms)
   tw.Flush()
   Dim bytes As Byte() = ms.ToArray()
   ms.Close()
   Response.Clear()
   Response.ContentType = "application/force-download"
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; 
       filename=file1.txt")
   Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
   Response.[End]()
```

The problem is that the gridview doesn't show.

I've noticed that if I don't download the file, the gridview appears and shows it's data correctly.  With the download, the gridview won't show at all.  Not even the empty data information.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot download a file AND update the UI, You can only send one item at a time. If you want to do both you will need to open the download in a new window or use a jquery solution.